# How to run Selenium + Maven tests on specific browser which is mentioned in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml

By mentioning parameter tag like following in testng.xml:

```
<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"></parameter>
```

and using following code:

```
@Parameters({"browser"})
public void test(String browser){ ... }
```

we can instantiate webdriver object for specific browser and run Selenium test on that browser.

But how can we achieve same using Selenium + Maven? I mean by mentioning browser name somewhere in testng.xml or pom.xml.

In order to achieve that, I went through **Specifying Test Parameters** section from http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html but I didn't understand how parameters from Maven can be passed into your TestNG test.

Can someone help me on how this can be achieved or point me documentation/repository which will help me to achieve this?

Comment: Note, if you're running Selenium tests, these are likely to be 'integration' rather than 'unit' tests with specific environmental setup requirements.  You may find [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html) more suitable.  The difference is, failsafe will always run the tear-down (post-integration-test phase) steps afterwards, wheras surefire will just stop.  Configuration is otherwise pretty similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is if you are using something like below in your `pom.xml`, you will not be able to access the value via the annotation `@Parameters`.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <propertyName>firefox</propertyName>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

`@Parameters` is a concept which only applies when parameters are passed via a TestNG suite file or programmatically by manipulating the `Map<String, String>` data structure which contains the `@Parameters`.

To access the system property defined you would use `System.getProperty("propertyName");`

For example;

Accessing the system property in the test method.

```
@Test
public void test() { 
  String browser = System.getProperty("browser");
}
```

Or accessing the system property in a before step and adding it the TestNG data structure.

```
@BeforeSuite
public void before(ITestContext ctx) {
  ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getParameters().put("browser"), System.getProperty("browser");
}

@Test
@Parameters({"browser"})
public void test(String browser) {
  //....
}
```

Comment: Doug, in case of testng parameter `<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"></parameter>`, parameter name is `browser` and value is `Firefox` but in pom.xml we've `<propertyName>firefox</propertyName>`, but I didn't understand what is here property name and what is property value.

Comment: Doug, got it!!! It's like `<propertyName>propertyValue</propertyName>`. Means if I want `browser=firefox`, I'll have to mention `<browser>firefox</browser>`. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can define your browser configuration in testNG.xml(exactly as you mentioned ) and simply kick start it using pom.xml.

**You don't need to mention any browser specific details in POM.xml**.I believe maven simply executes your testNG file with whatover configuration provided unless it requires an external libs/jars.

If you are facing any specific issues/errors while doing the same then share the details.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, your answer was helpful! I upvoted :) but I was looking for something that Doug answered.